# Import XML feed in tx_news /eventnews

Tags: xml, typo3, typo3-7.6.x, tx-news

Import of XML feed is working well with extension news_importicsxml. 
The connected extension eventnews is also used.

When importing data a checkbox is event has to be set to true, to show these imported news in calendar view.

Is it possible to import Imagedata or URL into news extension?

Need really help for this.

thx
Wolfgang

Versions:
Typo3 7.6.18
news 6.0.0
eventnews 2.0.1
news_importicsxml 2.1.1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version (try https://github.com/georgringer/eventnews) can import media elements of an RSS feed as well.

Regarding the checkbox: This needs to be done with a custom signal slot implementation provided by you. Take a look at https://github.com/georgringer/news_importicsxml/blob/master/Classes/Aspect/NewsImportAspect.php how this can be done.

Comment: Thx. Regarding the checkbox your hint was helpful and is now working.

Import media is still not working with this xml:

Comment: Import media is still not working with this xml tag. 
Also description does not fill teaser field.

<description>Example description</description>        <image>https://www.externalDomain.de/myimage.jpg</image>

Any idea?

Comment: the extension supports the enclosure tag, see https://www.w3schools.com/xml/rss_tag_enclosure.asp, no other tag

Comment: ah, ok, thx.
And what is about the description » teaser text? Is this working?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding image import I just faced the same problem: images in `<enclosure>` tags were not being imported into the database. Version of news_importicsxml is 3.0.0, I cloned it from https://github.com/georgringer/news_importicsxml.git

I had to manually create a folder `fileadmin/news_import` to make it work. Maybe this is different when the extension is installed using composer. Found that out by code inspection. Maybe it helps someone stumbling about this again.